# where the build happens in Jenkins and how we can reduce build time?

Tags: jenkins, build, compilation, jenkins-pipeline

Where does the build happen? I know it is triggered by Jenkins, but what physical location is the compilation and packaging executed at?

Answer (score 0):

By default jenkins home directory is ~/.jenkins , that can also be changed by setting JENKINS_HOME.

- To understand jenkins directory structure refer below link

  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

Comment: Thanks Sanath.....Means it is the physical location(Home directory) where all the compilation and packaging executed at?

Comment: Yes physical machine where jenkins is installed execution happens, if there is master and slave nodes and jobs will be executed in slave-node ( execution happens in slave machine )

Comment: How we can check it is master or slave nodes?

Comment: if you configured jenkins as master/slave setup physically 2 vm ,
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows,
when you run jenkins master tells slave to run those jobs, and in build history you will see on which slave its got executed

Comment: What happens in home directory like we have putted D:\Jenkins....I saw many files like Jenkins.exe n many XMLs....These are the files which do compilation and packaging.

Comment: No even in windows it will be under C:\Users\user\.jenkins by default

Comment: Sanath.... I just want to know my task is to reduce build time. Is it the Compilation or location of execution.  Which matters the most in order to reduce time.

Comment: it is nothing to do with location , as you asked for location as 1st question.
compilation matters more,like cpu,mem,n/w speed if its cloning...etc

Comment: Sanath Is it Correct ?......Vendor provided scripts we shouldn't alter them unless there's a critical reason. Those are super complex.The compilation and packaging process is known to take time in Software so there's probably not much optimisation we can do. One good practice is to run the build process on a machine with an SSD - that significantly speeds things up.

Comment: yes optimizing on resource will be the first step which will speed up the thinghs

Comment: SSDs are Solid state devices.....Do you have any idea....Any steps or links to perform. Thanks fro support